# A chat notification Indicator

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, badge

Guys look at the screen shot. I am building a chat window to show unread messages. Though it works fine. [code window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHHty.png)

and the [output window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXWux.png)

I just can't figure out a simple condition when the count is 0 I want to hide the entire badge.

```
 <Badge
                                  badgeContent={jobcard.jobcard_count.map(
                                    (row2) => {
                                      if (row2.jobcard_id === row._id)
                                        return row2.count;
                                    }
                                  )}
                                  color="primary"
                                >
                                  <MailIcon />
                                </Badge>
```

Comment: well, I am not sure if I understood correctly, but if your badgeContent is the number ot not readed notifications, maybe you can say sth like:  return row2.count===0? null: row2.count,

Comment: tried but no luck?

Answer (score 1):

Try conditional rendering with short circuit evaluation, rather than doing the row2.count logic inside the badgeContent, move it out of the Badge Component and return a Badge Component only if row2.count is greater than 0.

```
{
    jobcard.jobcard_count.map(
      (row2) => {
        if (row2.jobcard_id === row._id)
          row2.count > 0 && <Badge badgeContent={row2.count} color="primary"><MailIcon /></Badge>;
      }
  )
}
```

Comment: how can row2.count be evalueted before? its param in map()? yet tested and as i thought it didn't work

Comment: hey, yeah you are right, I assumed row2 was available in the outer scope. Could you share the entire code where you are using 'row' as the looping variable?

Comment: can I know your mail id or something like that to share code? code is bit long so this doesn't allow to paste

Comment: You could use a pasting service like pastebin or sth and post the link here.

Comment: @SabyasachiRout I edited the answer after checking your code. The major change is, rather than doing the row2.count logic inside the badgeContent, move it out of the Badge Component and return a Badge Component only if row2.count is greater than 0.

Answer (score 0):

You could hide the entire badge if the count is 0, using an if-statement. In the else-part you should put the MailIcon.

Alternatively, you could add a class if the count is 0, which hides the badge using CSS.